# Vector of maps of objects

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

I want to push an a map that contains an instance of a class to a vector. The following code is used

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

class Obj {
 public:
  Obj() {}
  Obj(std::string type) : type(type) {}
  std::string type;
  std::string value;
};

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
 std::vector< std::map<std::string, Obj> > v;
 v.push_back(std::make_pair("test", Obj("testtype")));

 return 0;
}
```

Could someone please explain to me why the `push_back` is failing? I could give you the errors thrown but they are way to too much for this case i think.

Comment: Looks like you are putting in a `pair` where a `map` should be added. If I remember correctly `pairs` are internal to maps

Comment: g++ says: `test.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
test.cpp:17:53: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::map<std::basic_string<char>, Obj> >::push_back(std::pair<const char*, Obj>)'` so yes, must be it, a map and a pair are not the same thing

Comment: It is failing because you are not pushing a map into the vector.

Comment: Why are you trying to push pair instead of map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 std::make_pair("test", Obj("testtype");
```

According to [std::mak_pair documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair)

> **std::make_pair**
>   Creates a std::pair object, deducing the target type from the types of arguments.

`v` expect that you push a `std::map` object into it, but you are pushing an object of `std::pair`. `std::map` and `std::pair` are two different things.

You may try:

```
 std::map<std::string, Obj> mymap;
 mymap["test"] = Obj("testtype");
 v.push_back(mymap);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can this work?

```
int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
 std::vector< std::map<std::string, Obj> > v;
 std::map<std::string, Obj> m;

 m["test"] = Obj("testtype");

 v.push_back(m);

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
std::vector<std::map<std::string, Obj>> v;
std::map<std::string,Obj> v_map;
v_map.insert(std::pair(std::string("test"),Obj("testtype")));
v.push_back(v_map);
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector< std::map<std::string, Obj> > v;` should be  :

`std::vector< std::pair<std::string, Obj> > v;`

`std::pair` and `std::map` are different